# How to find min and max value from an arrary in python?

Tags: python, json, api

I have fetched data from API and trying to perform some calculations. I was able to fetch the values but could not find min and max values.

```
# importing libraries

import json
import requests

# loading data from BOM API
response = requests.get("http://www.bom.gov.au/fwo/IDN60701/IDN60701.94598.json")
bom_dict = json.loads(response.text)

press_collection = []

# extracting data

for values in bom_dict['observations']['data']:
    press_collection.append(values['press']) // got
this
press
from json

for val in range(len(press_collection)):

print("the pressure value is \n", press_collection[val])
#calculating minimum , maximum and average pressure
```

I am new to Python. So please need help.

Comment: Maybe you need to fix it with a right indent?

Comment: indent is working fine...

Answer (score 0):

If press_collection contains only numeric data (int, float etc.)
Then you could do :

```
min(press_collection) #minimum
max(press_collection) #maximum
sum(press_collection)/len(press_collection) #average
```

Comment: thank you bro...but where should i place this code??

Comment: At the end of your code should be fine, do not put it inside any loop.

Comment: the value are displaying in a loop. I just need to print single values for each..

Comment: Remove this statement "for val in range(len(press_collection)):"